# Translate ACL Descriptors to Security Group names

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

When using the AzDO REST API Security Endpoint, I'm trying to determine which ACE dictionary in an Access Control List belongs to a specific security group.

Link to Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

the JSON output includes a section called "acesDictionary". Each element in this section contains a "descriptor" key.

Example:

```
{
            "inheritPermissions": false,
            "token": "a0d66bdf-2d5a-48a5-822b-1d6c4e8f20a2",
            "acesDictionary": {
                "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity;53bed6f5-352c-4160-b88e-275616c09042:Build:6b1dcbeb-af9b-4218-ac72-fc84b6dce8de": {
                    "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity;53bed6f5-352c-4160-b88e-275616c09042:Build:6b1dcbeb-af9b-4218-ac72-fc84b6dce8de",
                    "allow": 8225,
                    "deny": 0
                }.......truncated.
```

Through trial and error, I've been able to determine that one of the elements modifies permission for project contributors for a specific release pipeline.  What I cannot figure out is how to translate the "descriptor" to the equivalent [ProjectName]SecurityGroupName.  I need to be able to do this so I can modify the permission via a script for dozens of projects with dozens of release and build pipelines each.

Any advice on which endpoint to use would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the identity of the descriptor using this undocumented API:

**Disclaimer**: Any API that is not publicly documented is subject to change at anytime.

https://**vssps**.dev.azure.com/*{organization}*/_apis/identities?descriptors=*{IdentityDescriptor}*

From there you can grab the security group from ProviderDisplayName.

Example response:

```
{  
Id:"5b250e58-8dbf-4111-8eab-8735e1058a11",
Descriptor:{  
  IdentityType:"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity",
  Identifier:"S-1-9-2551374245-3827430512-2595430990-2155723759-1767818319-0-0-0-0-3"
},
ProviderDisplayName:"[ExampleProjectName]\Project Valid Users",
CustomDisplayName:null,
DisplayName:"[ExampleProjectName]\Project Valid Users",
IsActive:true,
UniqueUserId:0,
IsContainer:true,
Members:[ ],
MemberOf:[ ],
Properties:{  
   SchemaClassName:"Group",
   Description:"Members of this group have access to the team project.",
   Domain:"vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/13f75242-3248-4999-a76c-47f6ec2580a4",
   Account:"Project Valid Users",
   SecurityGroup:"SecurityGroup",
   SpecialType:"EveryoneApplicationGroup",
   ScopeId:"70f521e4-b39a-4422-807d-bbef695ec44f",
   ScopeType:"TeamProject",
   LocalScopeId:"13g75242-3248-4999-a76c-47f6ec2580a4",
   SecuringHostId:"23ad9cb9-521b-46c2-a7b0-fbd454ac7275",
   ScopeName:"ExampleProjectName",
   VirtualPlugin:""
 }
```

Comment: Seems a bit odd that the only way to find the required information for a supported API is to use an unsupported, undocumented API.